# If DBCC CheckDB says my database is OK, is it OK?

Tags: sql-server, disaster-recovery, dbcc

I'm thinking my way through some disaster recovery scenarios. How does this one sound?

- A server running SQL Server 2008 or 2005 suddenly loses power (e.g. the plug gets pulled)
- When turned back on, the Operating system recovers OK and there are no hard-drive corruptions. The SQL Logs say DBCC CheckDB has been run on all databases and they are all OK.

Should the server be considered OK in this scenario, or should SQL backups be restored anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message you get on the log that says `"...CHECKDB for database 'YourDatabase' finished without errors on 2010...."` doesnt mean SQL Server runs DBCC at startup; it is an informational message that just tells you when the last time DBCC was run on the databases(look at the dates carefully). So as @TomTom said you may need to run DBCC manually again to check integrity of your database. Also if you have big maintenance window its best practice to regularly schedule and run daily/weekly or monthly DBCC checks otherwise you can restore a backup and run DBCC against it to avoid the overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you run DBCC CHECKDB a last time manually. But otherwise I would consider the server to be ok.